# Access to native android.webkit.WebView instance from JavaFXPorts Webview

Tags: android, android-webview, javafx-8, javafxports, javafx-webengine

I want to implement java-to-javascript method call via

`WebView.getEngine().executeScript("browserMessagingServicePush('Push data from Java to JS')");`

on Android using javafxports 8.60.9, but got

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
...
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:860)
```

exception.

How can I get reference to Android's native WebView to implement something like this?

```
WebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "JSInterface");
```

Or there is some other workaround?

Comment: @José Pereda, could you please help me with this issue? :)

Comment: Without looking at the code, I assume, you could try the reflection approach. But you would need to find it out for yourself. Otherwise it should be on Androids view stack. If there is a way to traverse it, you could do that via the FXActivity...

Comment: This is particulary hard to find: https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/8u-dev-rt contains code for `FXActivity` and `InternalWebView` (where the native WebView is used). The latter seems to be a) from OpenJFX and b) be added to the native View stack in somewhere in the code (see line 289 `FXActivity.getViewGroup().addView(iwv.nativeWebView, layout);`). The whole things seems to be ripped of from the OpenJFX code base (see here https://github.com/Debian/openjfx/blob/master/modules/web/src/android/java/com/sun/webkit/NativeWebView.java ).

Comment: With `FXActivity.getViewGroup().getChildCount()` and `FXActivity.getViewGroup().getChildAt(index)` you should be able to walk over the native components, such as the internal WebView. Hope, this helps. If needed I can also compile a full answer for this (would help my reputation, as well :-) )

Comment: I'm afraid your attempt won't work. I did try a very dirty hack to get access to the native web view (in the line of what it is proposed above), and while I was able to add the JS interface, it didn't work (it wasn't called), as it seems it has to be added in the `initialize` [method](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/8u-dev-rt/src/f65178683d09d16f27241a8091408bcd66625d26/modules/graphics/src/dalvik/java/com/oracle/dalvik/InternalWebView.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#InternalWebView.java-86).

Comment: @dzim, what do you mean with ripped off? 8u-dev-rt is a fork of the openJFX project.

Comment: I meant, that the package of the FXActivity was renamed to javafxports. ;-) it was not meant as an offense! I simply looked as far as I could and noticed that difference. Could you use sth. like byte buddy to change the original class?

Comment: @José have you added the interface according to this tutorial? https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html I mean did you add the necessary annotation?

Comment: Yes, I did. I spent a few hours trying without success, the JS interface was never called.

Comment: Have you asked your other pals over at Gluon? Maybe they've got an idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update on Solution**

I found a solution to executing JavaScript using Android native WebView (and not using JavaFX WebView) from a JavaFXPorts application - see code below.
I solved the navigation to and from my JavaFX stage and Android WebView (in my 1st answer on 25 February 2018) by using 2 Activities: my main activity (JavaFX Stage) invokes a 2nd Activity (Android WebView) and passes the URL I want to display and when the 2nd  Activity finishes it passes back a result string. You can exit the 2nd Activity by executing finish() or using the back button. You need to add an additional entry in the AndroidManifest.xml for the 2nd Activity.

Here's my main activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafxports.android.FXActivity;

/*****************************************
   This is the main activity
******************************************/
public class MainActivity extends FXActivity {

    private static final int SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

    protected void webView() {

        Platform.runLater( () -> {
                String url ="http://www.example.com";
                Intent intent = new Intent(FXActivity.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), Test.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", url);

                // Add result handler
                FXActivity.getInstance().setOnActivityResultHandler((requestCode, resultCode, data) ->
                    switch (requestCode) {
                        case SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE:
                             //if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {}

                             // get String data from Intent
                             String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
                             System.out.println("result = " + result);
                             break;

                        default:                             
                             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                             break;
                     }
                });

                FXActivity.getInstance().startActivityForResult(intent, SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        });

    }
}
```

Here's my 2nd Activity (Android WebView):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

/*****************************************
    This is the 2nd activity
******************************************/
public class Test extends Activity {
    private String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            url = bundle.getString("url");
        }
        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(webClient);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }


    WebViewClient webClient = new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         String title = view.getTitle();
         System.out.println("onpagefinished title = "+view.getTitle());

         view.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return document.documentElement.outerHTML})();",
                  new ValueCallback<String>() {

                      @Override
                      public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                        System.out.println("evaluateJavascript html = "+html);

                        if (<exit 2nd activity condition>) {
                            // put the String to pass back into an Intent and close this activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.putExtra("result", "this is the result string");
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                            finishAndRemoveTask();                  // takes you back to main activity
                        }
                      }
             });
    }
    };

}
```

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml which I manually changed to add the 2nd Activity for Test.class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
    <application android:label="APP" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
            <activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:label="Main" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
                    <meta-data android:name="main.class" android:value="com.example.Launcher"/>
                    <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>
                    <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.Test"
                android:label="Test"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

When instantiating MainActivity it crashes with "can't create a handle without a Looper.prepare()". A handle is not explicitly created and so it's not clear which handle is referenced. Solution: create a looper and then after
instantiation destroy it. You can only issue Looper.prepare() once otherwise it crashes. Subsequent calls to MainActivity.webView() work without Looper. Here's my code:

```
Looper.prepare();
new MainActivity();
Looper.myLooper().quitSafely();
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I found a solution to executing JavaScript using Android native WebView (and not using JavaFX WebView) from a JavaFXPorts application:

```
public class AndroidNativeService extends Activity implements NativeService {
    private Stage stage;

    public void myWebview(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;

        FXActivity.getInstance().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {     
            @Override
            public void run() {             
                WebView webView = new WebView(FXActivity.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
                FXActivity.getInstance().setContentView(webView);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                webView.setWebViewClient(webClient);
                webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/index.html");
            }
        });
    }

    WebViewClient webClient = new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // super.onPageFinished(view, url);          
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> onpagefinished title = "+view.getTitle());

            view.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return document.documentElement.outerHTML})();", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> evaluateJavascript html = "+html);
                    // view.goBack();
                    // stage.show(); # get error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = main
                }
            });
        }
    };

}
```

I invoke this class using:

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override 
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        Platform.runLater( () ->  {
            GoNativePlatform goNativePlatform =  GoNativePlatformFactory.getPlatform();
            Looper.prepare(); // if don't use this then get error Looper.prepare() not set
            goNativePlatform.getNativeService().myWebView(stage);   
        });
        return null;
    }
};

Thread th = new Thread(task);
th.start();
```

I copied "Implements NativeService" as declared on my class statement from [Handling Android Native Activities like a Pro](http://gluonhq.com/handling-android-native-activities-like-a-pro/) though this isn't absolutely necessary to make this work.
When trying to implement JavaFX WebView (as opposed to Android Native WebView) with this JavaFX WebView code:

```
Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
getTitle(webView.getEngine());
String html = (String) webView.getEngine().executeScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML");
```

I got either nulls or "not supported yet" when running on Android though the code worked OK on desktop. (Haven't tried yet on IOS but I want to implement too here). 
I want to retrieve the webpage title and execute javascript to retrieve other data from a webpage.
And so my solution was to use Android Native WebView instead of JavaFX WebView when running on Android.
Here's my complete code:

```
public class AndroidNativeService extends Activity implements NativeService {
    private Stage stage;

    public void myWebview(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;

        FXActivity.getInstance().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {     
            @Override
            public void run() {             
                WebView webView = new WebView(FXActivity.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
                FXActivity.getInstance().setContentView(webView);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                webView.setWebViewClient(webClient);
                webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/index.html");

                webView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> onClick()");
                        // webView.goBack();
                    }
                }); 
            }
        });
    }

    WebViewClient webClient = new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // super.onPageFinished(view, url);          
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> onpagefinished title = "+view.getTitle());

            view.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return document.documentElement.outerHTML})();", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> evaluateJavascript html = "+html);
                    // view.goBack();
                    // stage.show(); # get error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = main
                }
            });
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Back Button Pressed");
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        super.onBackPressed();
        // FXActivity.getInstance().finish();
    }

}
```

Although I have successfully displayed the desired webpage, retrieved the title and executed some JavaScript, I am struggling to close the webpage and return to the JavaFX stage. 
My 2 callbacks above `onBackPressed()` and `OnClickListener` don't work and are not invoked (can't see the `System.out.println`). You can see from above I am trying and struggling to use these alternatives:

- `webView.goBack();`
- `stage.show();    // get error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = main`
- `FXActivity.getInstance().finish();`

But I am only managing to terminate the whole app rather than return to the JavaFX stage (even though I am passing it's value into this class). Any thoughts?

**PS**: `Looper.prepare();` is necessary to be able to invoke this code though I don't understand what I am doing here?